# Is there a way of creating AWS EC2 instance with postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, postman

I want to create an **EC2 instance** with **Postman** but, I couldn't find anything on the internet? Is there a way of doing this? or should I use **aws-cli** instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in AWS is an API that can be hit directly or via CLI or SDK. All those do is make the same calls you'd have to make. The advantage to using the CLI or SDK is that they manage the auth for you, which is no trivial matter. The following document gives you a place to start looking at all the options for using AWS APIs.

[Making API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)